# ExecuteSQL Processor in Apache Nifi

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, apache-nifi

I am facing a problem while working with Apache Nifi. Is there a way to stop ExecuteSQL processor once it is completed fetching all the data in the table, instead of fetching repeatedly until I stop it manually?

Comment: ,RightClick the processor,Goto Scheduling tab and specify RunSchedule as 1 day ,It will run once

Answer (score 5):

Generally processors are meant to be scheduled on some frequency through their scheduling tab. Processors in the middle of the graph with incoming relationships usually leave their scheduling at 0 seconds, which means run as fast as possible when data is queue. Source processors typically run on some interval based on Timer Driver or Cron Driven scheduling.

That being said... ExecuteSQL supports being triggered by incoming flow files, so you might be able to do something like put a ListenHTTP processor in front of ExecuteSQL and whenever you want to trigger it you would invoke the http end-point for ListenHTTP. This way you can leave it running, but it will only be triggered when you want it to be.